# Automatic vendor chunk with dynamic code splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, commonschunkplugin

**How my application is split into chunks**

My applications main and only entry chunk contains some common logic that is reused throughout the application such has layouting or helper methods and components related to authentication such as login/registration dialogs. This chunk has `react`, `react-dom`, `redux`, `react-router` and some other libs from `node_modules` directory in its dependency tree because they are being used by the authentication components.

All those dependencies are bundled into an `app.js` file that is always initially loaded. Whenever the user starts to use some part of the application that requires a logged in user - such as dashboards, forms and other app functionality, additional javascript chunks comprising that functionality are loaded. Those additional chunks are automatically generated by `webpack` because of `import()` calls distributed throughout the applications code.

When a new user loads the app and is not logged in, `app.js` is loaded and the user is presented with a login mask. After a user has successfully logged in and is redirected to the main dashboard, the code of the dashboard is asynchronously loaded. This code, automatically built into a `dashboard.js` chunk by `webpack`, also depends on a lot of the libraries already baked into the `app.js` chunk (e.g. `react`, `react-dom` etc). Because the `dashboard.js` chunk does not duplicate those libraries, it is quite small compared to the `app.js`.

To make good use of browser caching, all of those chunks (in this simplified
example: the entry chunk `app.js` and the dynamic chunk `dashboard.js`) have a
`[chunkhash]` in their name. In comparison to library code from `node_modules`, both the code of the dynamic chunks and the parts of the `app.js` that are actual application code change quite a lot.

**What i would like to do**

I would like to configure `webpack` in a way that detects which libraries from
`node_modules` are used in more than 2 (or any configurable number) of chunks and
automatically split those into an additional chunk, `vendor.js`.

This chunk should contain the library parts of the current `app.js` that don't change often so the user doesn't often re-download library code.

From what i've understood, something like this can be done with
`CommonsChunkPlugin` when manually adding lots of entry chunks. Can i also do
this with dynamic code splitting performed with `import()` calls?

*Example*

I might use `lodash.partialRight` somewhere in in `dashboard.js`. As long as it is only used there, i want it to be bundled with `dashboard.js`. The moment i also use it in the login/registration process, it should not be bundled into the
`app.js` the way it is now but should instead automatically be bundled into `vendor.js` with other libraries that are re-used across chunks.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to list out the libraries that you want to be added to vendor.js explicitly. https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code

The rest of your code and node_modules that are not listed in "vendor" will be split automatically by webpack. So the more libraries you list in

```
vendor: ["jquery", "underscore", ...],
```

the larger vendor.js file is but with less frequent re-download from your users.

Comment: This is not what i'm aiming for. I want this automated.